# É possível ter mais de uma rota "post" em um controller .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, controller

Estou começando um projeto de uma API C#.NET Core.
Quando crio um controller do tipo "API Controller with read/write actions" ele cria as actions disponíveis.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace Service.Login.Controllers {
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<TestesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/<TestesController>/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<TestesController>
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<TestesController>/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<TestesController>/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Como faço para ter 2 actions do tipo POST? Por exemplo:

```
// POST api/<TestesController>
[HttpPost]
public string PostA([FromBody] string value)
{
  return "A";
}

// POST api/<TestesController>
[HttpPost]
public int PostB([FromBody] string value)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Já configurei a rota no Startup.cs...

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();}
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseResponseCompression();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: Qual o motivo para que você queria fazer isso, até pode, com outra rota, mas, qual é o objetivo principal?

Comment: Estou testando o que o C# me da de recursos, é um projeto de testes então não tenho exatamente um motivo para isso. Essa não é uma boa prática @VirgilioNovic?

Comment: E como seria esse processo "com outra rota"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando é criado o `template` padrão são criados os métodos `get`, `put`, `post` e `delete` com os seus *delegates* específicos na programação. Para adicionar um novo método `post` é preciso criar um método que tenha diferença dos outros e que seja especificado um rota diferente, *exemplo*:

```
// método padrão
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Source value)
{
    return Ok(new { @now = DateTime.Now, value });
}

// método que é diferente do padrão e que tem parâmetros diferentes
[HttpPost(), Route("service")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Source value, string name = null)
{
    return Ok(new { Now = DateTime.Now, value,Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay });
}
```

ou mude o nome do método com a configuração da rota.

```
[HttpPost(), Route("service")]
public IActionResult Post1([FromBody] Source value)
{
    return Ok(new { Now = DateTime.Now, value,Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay });
}
```

para chegar nessas duas rotas segue respectivamente os caminhos:

- `api/source`
- `api/source/service`

mas, isso não é muito usual